# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'sa' in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My code in web.config is as follows.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="IRSLogics_ClientsEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.ClientModel.csdl|res://*/Models.ClientModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.ClientModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=IRSLogics_Clients;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=dba@92701;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />      </connectionStrings>
```

Kindly suggest.Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error is pretty clear.  The login failed for the user `sa`.  Your connection string supplies these credentials: `user id=sa;password=dba@92701;` which are clearly incorrect.  This has nothing to do with MVC.  You'd get the same error if you try to login to the database through any application.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="IRSLogics_ClientsEntities" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=IRSLogics_Clients;User ID=sa;Password=dba@92701" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Also make sure that you have database named "IRSLogics_Clients" in your local sql server and you are able to access using given userid/password.